# Works in jsFiddle but not on the website?

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I built the below script to work with existing elements we don't control on the site and it was returning:

**Spend another £NaN to recieve free standard delivery**

so I went to write a query on stackOverflow to find out why and thought I would use JSfiddle to help, however the exact same code put into JSfiddle runs correctly and displays:

**Spend another £9 to recieve free standard delivery**

So I'm even more confused, any idea what could be the issue?:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var subTotal = ($('.totalSubtotal').text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
  var startTotal = 70.00;
  var total = startTotal - subTotal;


  $('#revealPromoBox').append('<div class="promoTotal">Spend another £' + total + ' to recieve free standard delivery</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="totalSubtotal">
  Sub-total:&nbsp;<strong data-oi-price="">£61</strong>
</div>


<h3 id="revealPromoBox"></h3>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqasjbwy/)

Comment: See the **Related** section on the right? Try any of those same questions. Make sure jQuery is loaded on your site and check your console for errors.

Comment: check out the browser console for errors.

Comment: The only reason you could get `NaN` is if `subTotal` contains a string value that cannot be converted to a number. Debug your code and inspect what the value is on your website. E.g. if the string is something like `"3.4.5"`, then that would be converted to `NaN`.

Comment: there is likely more than one totalSubtotal on the site and only one here and in JSFiddle - `10.0030.00` would be NaN :)

Comment: @mplungjan: Good idea. *"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."* https://api.jquery.com/text/ One of the few(?) methods that doesn't only apply to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely more than one totalSubtotal on the site and only one here and in JSFiddle - 10.0030.00 would be NaN since .text() will concatenate the strings it finds

```js
$(function() {

  var subTotal = 0;
  $('.totalSubtotal').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    subTotal += isNaN(val)?0:parseFloat(val);
  });
  var startTotal = 70.00;
  var total = startTotal - subTotal;


  $('#revealPromoBox').append('<div class="promoTotal">Spend another £' + total.toFixed(2) + ' to recieve free standard delivery</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="totalSubtotal">
  Sub-total:&nbsp;<strong data-oi-price="">£11.00</strong>
</div>
<div class="totalSubtotal">
  Sub-total:&nbsp;<strong data-oi-price="">£21.00</strong>
</div>


<h3 id="revealPromoBox"></h3>
```